# How to find out total number of pages related to project in AEM

Tags: migration, aem

I want to get total number of pages related to my project in AEM.Actually i am working on a migration project.So i need to calculate total number of pages before and after migration.

Please somebody help.How can i get this? I am new to AEM.Help me

Answer (score 2):

> total number of pages related to my project in AEM

Depending on what the content structure of your site is and what you consider *pages related to your project*, this may become a simple JCR Query or a somewhat complex one.

The following XPath query

```
/jcr:root/content/mysite//*[jcr:primaryType='cq:Page'])
```

would get you the number of all pages in the `mysite` content tree.

However, you should keep in mind that if you have many pages, you may end up causing a significant load on the environment in question.

That's certainly **not something you should be running in a production environment**.

If for some reason you can't assume that all pages within a specific content tree are related to your project, you can be more specific in the query. You could query by templates or component resource types to isolate specific page types.

The easiest way to run queries in AEM is to use CRXDE:

[image: Link to the query tool in CRXDE]

Here's how you could configure it to give you the answer to your question:

[image: Query tool in CRXDE]

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple JCR Query that would find items containing property `jcr:primaryType` being `cq:Page` within `/content` would work